# Resize Iframe Height as per content with in the Iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, expand

[image: at default before expand][image: when expanded]
so far what i research seems not be help. I am not jquery sabbie but it seems that it's not working. There are links within the iframe and once you click on each link, it expands and give you the content for that link. well the iframe height does not move along with it. here is my code. Here is what is in the header.

```
<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function () {$('iframe').iframeAutoHeight({debug: true});});</script>
```

body tag:

```
<iframe src="http://www.promero.com/defaultNewsTest.asp" class="auto-height"scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe><script>$('iframe.auto-height').iframeAutoHeight({minHeight: 240});</script>
```

the site is http://promerostage.promero.com/

Comment: put that in the edited OP, it is hard to look at in a comment

Comment: I think once iframe size is set thats cannot be changed from inside of the iframe what so ever you set the height to be..

Comment: there where to many spaces, i fixed it.

Comment: @War10ck `type="text/javascript"` is only required in XHTML, not HTML. It's incorrect to tell someone to add the type attribute unless you know that they're using XHTML (we should be encouraging the use of HTML5 anyway).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following article. I hope it will gonna resolve your issue as there is the solution in it, you seek for.

http://sonspring.com/journal/jquery-iframe-sizing

Comment: it's not moving, any other suggestion?